# When to implement Comparable<super class of X> instead of Comparable<X>?

Tags: java, generics

```
class A { ... }


class B extends A implements Comparable<A> {
    int compareTo(A aobject) { ... }
}
```

Usually we implement `Comparable` with a type-parameter of `B`. But java allows using a super class, as well.

Is there a scenario where I really need to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance if you have also:

```
Class C extends A implements Comparable<A> {

int compareTo(A aobject) {
/* Implementations */
}
```

you could compare objects of class `B` and `C` together either with `c.compareTo(b)` or with `b.compareTo(c)`.